# Loading word into cp1 returns "adress out of range" error

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

Greeting!
I am currently doing some work on MIPS assembly for college purposes but after trying to mess around with floats I have been prompted with the error specified in the title after trying the following code:

```
lwc1 $f6, 20
```

What I want to do is load the number 20 into a cp1 register so I can compare it with other registers.
Any guess on what I am doing wrong?
ps: The exact error is as follows: Runtime exception at 0x0040003c: address out of range 0x00000014

Comment: You're loading an address instead of a constant. Try the "load immediate" brother of your command: `li.s $f6, 20`

Comment: MARS doesn't have `li.s`, but maybe some other environment does.  @JanezKuhar, do you know one?

Comment: @ErikEidt [SPIM](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spimsimulator/) supports that pseudo-instruction, I've just checked. I've also made a typo. So, `li.s $f6, 20.0` is a pseudo-instruction implemented by this pair of instructions: `lui $1, 0x41a0` followed by a `mtc1 $1, $f6`.

Comment: @ErikEidt using mtc1 worked just fine!! Thanks a lot for the help.